# ORA-03137: TTC protocol internal error

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, errors, alerts

I have 11g 2-node RAC.
My alert.log contains several ORA-03137 errors:

```
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl2/trace/orcl2_ora_10679.trc  (incident=149362):
ORA-03137: TTC protocol internal error : [12333] [4] [195] [23] [] [] [] []
Fri Jan 17 17:01:56 2014
Sweep [inc][149362]: completed
```

and incident files are created..

How to solve this error? It is generated almost in every 7-8 minutes.

Please Help.

Comment: Looks to me like you need contact Oracle support.

Comment: But maybe this other answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7844985/391445

Comment: What specific patch are you on? There are bugs that are fixed in later patchsets

Comment: @Phil I have 11.2.0.1.0

Comment: @kupa you have some patching to do then....